# script powershell to count the localusers

Tags: powershell, foreach

```
cls
$users= get-localuser
$i=0
$inactiv=0
Write-Host ***** stat of accounts *****
foreach ($user in $users)
     
      {
         if ($user.enabled -eq 'true')
           
           {
            Write-Host  account $user.name is active}
              
              elseif ($user.Enabled -eq 'false')
             { $inactiv= $inactiv+ $users[$i]
               $i+=1 
               write-host the number of inactive accounts is $inactif   }
             }
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: i want to count all the inactive account and i dont get the right result

Comment: i have one active user which is right but for inactive i have 4 on this pic

Comment: Can you use the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72985425/edit) and clarify that on your post?

Comment: i tried but i dont how i am new but from the elseif on this script when i want to count the inactive accounts on this pc that i have a problem

Comment: you were unable to edit your post to include what your question is about?

Comment: yes i cant edit it s say core format ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to list the users who are active, and inactive by their *Enabled* status property, using the same looping logic you can use:

```
Get-LocalUser | 
    ForEach-Object -Begin {
        $active, $inactive = 0
    } -Process {
        if ($_.Enabled) {
            $active++
            "User [{0}] is active." -f $_.Name
        }
        else {
            $inactive++
            "User [{0}] is inactive." -f $_.Name
        }
    } -End {
        "Total of active users is: $active"
        "Total of inactive users is: $inactive"
    }
```

Without more clarification or code errors you may be getting, this should give you the expected results according to your comments. Using the `.Where({})` operator you can get the number of active/inactive account as well:

```
$localusers = Get-LocalUser
$localUsers.Enabled.Where{$_ -eq $true}.Count
$localUsers.Enabled.Where{$_ -eq $false}.Count
```

Also, you should be comparing boolean values to other boolean values and not strings.

Comment: @gixer, glad I was able to help. Let me know if you need a better explanation.